word vectors using spacy module of python showing error
I'm trying to get the word vectors using the spacy module of python and using en_core_web_lg for creating the word vectors.
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf=TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)

df1['question1']=df1['question1'].apply(lambda x : str(x))
df1['question2']=df1['question2'].apply(lambda x : str(x))

tot_ques=list(df1['question1']) + list(df1['question2'])

tfidf.fit(tot_ques)

idfscore=dict(zip(tfidf.get_feature_names_out(),tfidf.idf_))
print(idfscore)

from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

vec1 = []
# Iterate through each question1
for qu1 in tqdm(list(df1['question1'])):
doc1 = nlp(qu1)

# Initialize sum of vectors and total IDF score
sum_vec = np.zeros(len(doc1[0].vector))  # Vector dimension from the first word
total_idf = 0.0  # Initialize the total IDF score

# Iterate through each word in the sentence
for word in doc1:
    vec = word.vector
    
    # Calculate IDF score for the word
    try:
        idf = idfscore(str(word))
    except:
        idf = 0.0
    
    # Accumulate weighted sum of word vectors
    sum_vec += vec * idf
    
    # Accumulate the total IDF score
    total_idf += idf

# Calculate the mean vector if total IDF score is not zero
if total_idf != 0:
    mean_vec = sum_vec / total_idf
else:
    mean_vec = sum_vec  # Fall back to sum_vec if total IDF is zero

# Append the mean vector to vec1
vec1.append(mean_vec)

# Assign the calculated vectors to the new column 'q1' in the dataframe
df1['q1'] = vec1`

But when I am looking at the values of column q1 it is showing 0 for every row.
